# Necesito saber el path de sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, powershell

Estoy haciendo una conexión a sql server mediante New-PSDrive, y necesito conocer la ruta raiz a lo que me deseo conectar, por ejemplo: 'SQLSERVER:\SQL\SERVERNAME\DEFAULT', pero no se como mirar dicha ruta.

Comment: Si tienes acceso al servidor por SSMS, puedes ver este valor en las propiedades de la BD.

Comment: Acá puedes ver como sacar las ubicaciones de los archivos: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15